# perfect continuous for a completed action

Tags: perfect-continuous

> I have cleaned my car :

this means I have finished cleaning my entire car and it focuses on the result = clean car

> I have been cleaning my car:

this doesn`t necessarily mean I have finished cleaning my entire car and it focuses on the activity = what I have been doing.

My question is: is it possible to say I have been cleaning my car, even when I have cleaned my entire car, but I just want to emphasize the activity? For example: What have you been doing today? I have been cleaning my car. (meaning my entire car) or do I have to say I have cleaned my car?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the perfect continuous will always *imply* that you are still doing the activity, unless you add more information.

> A.  What have you been up to today?
>   B.  I've been doing my homework, **but I just finished**.

Comment: Thank you, I thought the present continuous could be used for actions that have recently finished, but you can see the result in the present, like in this case a clean car.